# How to get the result of a gcloud command in golang?

Tags: shell, go, gcloud

Here is my code  :

```
package main

import (
    "os/exec"
    "log"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    out, err := exec.Command("bash", "-c", "gcloud auth application-default login").Output()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("The output is %s\n", out)
}
```

When i exec this code it opens me my browser with the good url ...
But i would like to get the url.

When i type this command  :

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```

in my shell i have  :

```
Your browser has been opened to visit:

    https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?redirect_uri=h***********************************
```

And that's the text that i would like to get with the Out in my program.

Any idea how to get it ?

edit here are 3 thigns that i've tested with no sucess

```
/*
out, err := exec.Command("bash", "-c", "gcloud auth application-default login").CombinedOutput()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Printf("The output is %s\n", out)

*/

cmd := exec.Command("bash", "-c", "gcloud auth application-default login")
cmdReader, err := cmd.StderrPipe()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "Error creating StdoutPipe for Cmd", err)
    os.Exit(1)
}

scanner := bufio.NewScanner(cmdReader)
        go func() {
    for scanner.Scan() {
        fmt.Printf(" out | %s\n", scanner.Text())
    }

}()



out, err := exec.Command("bash", "-c", "gcloud auth application-default login").Output()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Printf("The date is %s\n", out)
```

Regards and Thanks

Comment: Your code is correct, may be `gcloud` output is going to stderr, can you try `CombinedOutput()` instead `Output()`?

Comment: @jeevatkm i've edited seems not working :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it why your snippet doesn't work as expected.

Typically `CombinedOutput()` and `Output()` returns the result after completion of given command.

Here `gcloud` command didn't finish the execution, so we have to read it realtime. I have tested the below code snippet, it works.

```
cmd := exec.Command("bash", "-c", "gcloud auth application-default login")
stderr, err := cmd.StderrPipe()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

// Start command
if err = cmd.Start(); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

// prevent main() to exit before cmd completes
defer cmd.Wait()

// read cmd output and send it to stdout
// repalce os.Stderr as per your need
go io.Copy(os.Stdout, stderr)

fmt.Println("Standby to read...")
fmt.Println()
```

This is just an approach, implement yours. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

That message is printed to stderr, not stdout.